# Google Cloud - Data Sharing Options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

I am new to cloud based environment and currently I am experimenting GCP.
I have a use case wherein we need to share data ( both ways )to the external parties.

The steps I followed,

1. Created a bucket on GCS and uploaded the file using gsutil from my local machine.
2. Created a service account.

My doubt is how the external parties will access my bucket to get the files.
What are the available options ?

Thanks

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil#make_your_object_publicly_accessible for may the bucket accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can make both objects and buckets public [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) adding permissions of viewing (or any other permissions you want) to "allUsers".

You can also give access to specific users [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-manage-lists) (both to objects and buckets)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. I tried with Gcloud client and it works pretty well. Also I am thinking for putting an API from 3rd party to request and access the objects from the bucket.

My doubt now, is there a way to notify via an email when the bucket has a new object.